# PERMISSION DENIED on FEDORA 20, APACHE

Tags: php, linux, permissions, lamp, selinux

Last week I installed Fedora 20 on my computer, create a web server (LAMP) and change the Document Root to my Dropbox folder.

From

> /var/www/html

to

> /home/ivnbrv/Dropbox

At the start I found some problems with SELinux, googling I discovered that was solved in this way.

```
$ chcon-R-u system_u-t httpd_sys_content_t /home/ivnbrv/Dropbox
```

Then changing the owner of this directory which was set in

> /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
User ivnbrv 
Group apache



$ chown-R ivnbrv.apache /home/ivnbrv/Dropbox
```

Now when I try to upload a file using PHP

> move_uploaded_file ()

I see this error

> PHP Warning: move_uploaded_file (/
>   home/ivnbrv/Dropbox/Site/files/public/noticia/img/large/2010201.jpg):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in / home / ivnbrv / Dropbox
>   / Site / upload.php on line 113

What can i do to make this work???

Comment: Did you enable the proper `sebool` values? e.g. `httpd_builtin_scripting`, `httpd_enable_homedirs`, etc. What's the output of `# getsebool -a |grep -i http`?

Comment: `/home/ivnbrv/Dropbox/Site/upload.php` should have proper execute permissions, labeled with `httpd_sys_script_exec_t`; or w/e line 113 is referencing.

Comment: ILMostro is there a way to set script_exec recursively? to all php files on a specific directory? is it recommended?

Comment: take a look at [this page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/SELinux); it shows some examples on how to apply the file context with `chcon` and `restorecon`.

Comment: I've also updated my answer with this pertinent information:

    `# semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_script_exec_t '/home/ivnbrv/Dropbox/Site/.*\/php5?'`

It is also shown on the above-mentioned link at the bottom of that page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your situation is somewhat far from standard--i.e. your Document Root directory is within a homedir, among other things--I'd like to remind you that the following suggestions are provided solely for you to determine the main cause of your problem with permissions. Keep in mind that the most important point of the SELinux system is to provide the *minimum set of permissions needed*; therefore, these steps are probably not all necessary, as they may further reduce the security of your system.

**NOTE** Additionally, perhaps most important, you need to make sure that your DAC policy allows the necessary rwx permissions to your server, since SELinux only goes into effect **after** the DAC permissions are allowed; i.e. if apache is not allowed rwx on the directory/file the DAC policy blocks it and SELinux doesn't even handle it.

---

- Try changing the file context of the `public` directory and subdirs to `public_content_rw_t`.

  ```
  # semanage fcontext -a -t public_content_rw_t "/home/ivnbrv/Dropbox/Site/files/public(/.*)?"
  ```

followed by

```
    # restorecon -R -v /home/ivnbrv/Dropbox/Site/files/public/
```

- Furthermore, you should check to make sure you have the proper `sebooleans` enabled with:

  ```
  # getsebool -a |grep -i http
  ```

AFAIK, `httpd_builtin_scripting`, `httpd_can_network_connect`, and `httpd_enable_homedirs` should be set to **on**.

```
    # setsebool httpd_... on
```

Execute the command above for any booleans that need to be enabled. This change is temporary, however, unless you also add the `-P` option to `setsebool` to make it persistent.

- Check to make sure that your php-script(s) have the necessary file context with

  ```
  ls -alZ /path/to/dir/with/scripts
  ```

If not, you can change them to `httpd_sys_script_exec_t` by executing

```
    # semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_script_exec_t '/home/ivnbrv/Dropbox/Site/.*\/php5?'
    # semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_script_rw_t '/home/ivnbrv/Dropbox/Site/files/public/noticia/img(/.*)?'
    # restorecon -R -v /home/ivnbrv/Dropbox/
```

As always, take a look at [SELinux's wikipages](http://selinuxproject.org/page/Main_Page) for further details and information.  There's also a wealth of useful information available on the [fedora wiki pages](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SELinux) with numerous scenarios and workflow methods; as well as the official [Fedora Docs - Security Guide](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/19/html/Security_Guide/ch09.html#sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Introduction).

Answer (score 0):

in your /etc/http/conf/httpd find lines like this:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

And add something like this:

```
<Directory /home>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then restart you apache service

Answer (score 0):

Try set execution permission to: `/home/`, `/home/ivnbrv/`  and `/home/ivnbrv/Dropbox`:

```
chmod o+x /home/
chmod o+x /home/ivnbrv/
chmod o+x /home/ivnbrv/Dropbox
```

And restart your apache.

I recommend, add your user at group www-data (in my case) or apache:

```
adduser your-user www-data
```